# How do I use DatePicker to schedule local notifications in Swift?

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I am fairly new to iOS development. I thought it would be cool to use the DatePicker to schedule local notifications for an app I'm making.

I have `@Binding var date = Date()` initialized as the variable that will hold the user input from the `DatePicker("Enter a date", $date)`. I thought that I could set up the DatePicker in the struct that I am using for the SwiftUI components and pass the date to the function `scheduleNotification()` located in the `NotificationManager` class (Like I said I'm new so if this is a bad idea please say so).

```swift
class NotificationManager {
    static let instance = NotificationManager()

    //function that handles authorizing the notification.
    func scheduleNotification(date: Date) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "This is my first notification!"
        content.subtitle = "text"
        content.sound = .default
        content.badge = 1

        //What I did to extract the components from the variable
        let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)

        //This is where I'm unclear what to do. I have seen on tutorials where the DateComponents() gets initialized and the .hour, .weekday, etc. gets individually assigned in military time for the notification. How do I handle that in this situation?

        //The trigger for the notification
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: comps, repeats: true) //This is problematic code. In some of my attempts at this I get an error that says "Extra arguments at positions #1, #2 in call" and "Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call" and "insert 'coder: <#NSCoder#>'" Do I need to do anything with NSCoder for this to work? Or is that error related to my not setting up the date compontents correctly like I mentioned before?

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
}
```

I have checked all over the Internet for support and haven't much luck. I have been playing around with it but am still stuck.

Comment: The code you posted does not have any compiler warnings or errors.

Comment: You should not initialise a Binding, it should be `@Binding var date: Date` and the value is from the calling parent view. You could have `@State var date = Date()`. Show a complete code that compiles and run.

Comment: @CoderGirl I copied your code exactly and I do not get any warnings or errors. Maybe your project has some library or other code that is causing the issue due to some extension or other class with a conflicting name.

Comment: @HangerRash, Sorry! You are right!  I found my problem. The code does work. It was on me, I had a self inflicted error. Thank you so much!